# Aerospike AQL count(*) SQL analogue script

Tags: aerospike, nosql-aggregation, aql

Ok, so the problem is that I need to do aggregation queries on aerospike's aql console. Specifically, I would like to take an average of a bins of records in a set and to count all the records in a set. I am not sure how to even begin...

Answer (score 4):

`aql> SHOW SETS` will give you the numbers of objects in yours sets, with the column `n_objects`

Then, you use the `n_objects` values to calculate your average

Answer (score 1):

SQL-like aggregation functions are implemented in Aerospike using [stream UDFs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/developing_stream_udfs.html), which are written in Lua. A stream UDF is a [map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) operation that is applied on a stream of records returned from a scan or [secondary index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/query.html) query.

The stream UDF module (let's assume it's contained in the file `aggr_funcs.lua`) would implement COUNT(*) by returning `1` for each record it sees, and reducing to an aggregated integer value.

```
local function one(record)
  return 1
end

local function sum(v1, v2)
    return v1 + v2
end

function count_star(stream)
  return stream : map(one) : reduce(sum)
end
```

You would [register the UDF module](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/udf_management.html#registering-a-module) with the server, then invoke it. Here's an example of how you'd do that in Python using [`aerospike.Query.apply`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/query.html#aerospike.Query.apply):

```
import aerospike
from aerospike import predicates as p

config = {'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 3000)],
          'lua': {'system_path':'/usr/local/aerospike/lua/',
                  'user_path':'/usr/local/aerospike/usr-lua/'}}
client = aerospike.client(config).connect()

query = client.query('test', 'demo')
#query.where(p.between('my_val', 1, 9)) optionally use a WHERE predicate
query.apply('aggr_funcs', 'count_star')
num_records = query.results()
client.close()
```

However, you should get [metrics](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics) such as the number of objects using an [info command](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info). Aerospike has an info subsystem that is used by the command line tools such as [asinfo](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/asinfo), the [AMC](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/amc/user_guide) dashboard, and the [info](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.info) methods of the language clients.

To get the number of objects in the cluster:

```
asinfo -h 33.33.33.91 -v 'objects'
23773
```

You can also get the number of objects in a specific namespace. I have a two node cluster, and I'll query each one:

```
asinfo -h 33.33.33.91 -v 'namespace/test'
type=device;objects=23773;sub-objects=0;master-objects=12274;master-sub-objects=0;prole-objects=11499;prole-sub-objects=0;expired-objects=0;evicted-objects=0;set-deleted-objects=0;nsup-cycle-duration=0;nsup-cycle-sleep-pct=0;used-bytes-memory=2139672;data-used-bytes-memory=618200;index-used-bytes-memory=1521472;sindex-used-bytes-memory=0;free-pct-memory=99;max-void-time=202176396;non-expirable-objects=0;current-time=201744558;stop-writes=false;hwm-breached=false;available-bin-names=32765;used-bytes-disk=6085888;free-pct-disk=99;available_pct=99;memory-size=2147483648;high-water-disk-pct=50;high-water-memory-pct=60;evict-tenths-pct=5;evict-hist-buckets=10000;stop-writes-pct=90;cold-start-evict-ttl=4294967295;repl-factor=2;default-ttl=432000;max-ttl=0;conflict-resolution-policy=generation;single-bin=false;ldt-enabled=false;ldt-page-size=8192;enable-xdr=false;sets-enable-xdr=true;ns-forward-xdr-writes=false;allow-nonxdr-writes=true;allow-xdr-writes=true;disallow-null-setname=false;total-bytes-memory=2147483648;read-consistency-level-override=off;write-commit-level-override=off;migrate-order=5;migrate-sleep=1;migrate-tx-partitions-initial=4096;migrate-tx-partitions-remaining=0;migrate-rx-partitions-initial=4096;migrate-rx-partitions-remaining=0;migrate-tx-partitions-imbalance=0;total-bytes-disk=8589934592;defrag-lwm-pct=50;defrag-queue-min=0;defrag-sleep=1000;defrag-startup-minimum=10;flush-max-ms=1000;fsync-max-sec=0;max-write-cache=67108864;min-avail-pct=5;post-write-queue=0;data-in-memory=true;file=/opt/aerospike/data/test.dat;filesize=8589934592;writethreads=1;writecache=67108864;obj-size-hist-max=100

asinfo -h 33.33.33.92 -v 'namespace/test'
type=device;objects=23773;sub-objects=0;master-objects=11499;master-sub-objects=0;prole-objects=12274;prole-sub-objects=0;expired-objects=0;evicted-objects=0;set-deleted-objects=0;nsup-cycle-duration=0;nsup-cycle-sleep-pct=0;used-bytes-memory=2139672;data-used-bytes-memory=618200;index-used-bytes-memory=1521472;sindex-used-bytes-memory=0;free-pct-memory=99;max-void-time=202176396;non-expirable-objects=0;current-time=201744578;stop-writes=false;hwm-breached=false;available-bin-names=32765;used-bytes-disk=6085888;free-pct-disk=99;available_pct=99;memory-size=2147483648;high-water-disk-pct=50;high-water-memory-pct=60;evict-tenths-pct=5;evict-hist-buckets=10000;stop-writes-pct=90;cold-start-evict-ttl=4294967295;repl-factor=2;default-ttl=432000;max-ttl=0;conflict-resolution-policy=generation;single-bin=false;ldt-enabled=false;ldt-page-size=8192;enable-xdr=false;sets-enable-xdr=true;ns-forward-xdr-writes=false;allow-nonxdr-writes=true;allow-xdr-writes=true;disallow-null-setname=false;total-bytes-memory=2147483648;read-consistency-level-override=off;write-commit-level-override=off;migrate-order=5;migrate-sleep=1;migrate-tx-partitions-initial=4096;migrate-tx-partitions-remaining=0;migrate-rx-partitions-initial=4096;migrate-rx-partitions-remaining=0;migrate-tx-partitions-imbalance=0;total-bytes-disk=8589934592;defrag-lwm-pct=50;defrag-queue-min=0;defrag-sleep=1000;defrag-startup-minimum=10;flush-max-ms=1000;fsync-max-sec=0;max-write-cache=67108864;min-avail-pct=5;post-write-queue=0;data-in-memory=true;file=/opt/aerospike/data/test.dat;filesize=8589934592;writethreads=1;writecache=67108864;obj-size-hist-max=100
```

Notice that the value of `master-objects` on each of the nodes adds up together to the cluster-wide `objects` value.

To get the number of objects in a set:

```
asinfo -h 33.33.33.91 -v 'sets/test/demo'
n_objects=23771:n-bytes-memory=618046:stop-writes-count=0:set-enable-xdr=use-default:disable-eviction=false:set-delete=false;
```

Comment: Good answer. Thanks. Aerospike's docs can be rather opaque, and you description is clear.

Comment: Since I last answered that there’s been work on a Presto connector for Aerospike. Both Presto and Spark with the connectors can do very expressive SQL with predicates pushed down to Aerospike so the compute is split between them